# How to create XML String in iPhone to use in web-service requests?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml, nsxml

I want to create XML string to be sent to server through web-service. How do I do it natively in iPhone? Or do I have to use any third party library?
I was not able to download GDATA for iPhone. Any else available? Or any other way to do it?

Please help,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create XML file with StringWithFormat method or Some of XML parser allow write XML as well. Please refer link of Parser for writing XML

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON parser also....

You may want to refer to SBJSON Framework which is frequently used for objective-C, I have used this framework in may of my iOS Apps.

You may get a reference about it from these links:

https://github.com/stig/json-framework

http://stig.github.com/json-framework/

Example Code: Also here is an example on, How to parse JSON with SBJSON Parser:

How to parse JSON into Objective C - SBJSON

http://jasarien.com/?p=428